# Why doesn't my iAd banner appear when theres an error loading my FB Audience Network banner ad?

Tags: swift, iad, facebook-audience-network

I have iAds and Facebook's Audience Network as my two banner ads. When there is an error loading my Audience Network's banner ad I want my iAd banner to appear. When I try to call it in this function my iAd banner does not appear. I'm testing this on my device and have set the developers settings fill rate to 0%. My Audience Network's banner ad still shows when I do this. What am I doing wrong?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate,
        ADInterstitialAdDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate,
    SKPaymentTransactionObserver, ChartboostDelegate, FBAdViewDelegate {

    var productID: NSString!
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
            skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            //scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
            loadFbAds()
        }

        func loadFbAds() {
            if defaults.boolForKey("removeAdsPurchased") == false {
                let width = self.view.frame.size.width
                let height = self.view.frame.size.height / 10

                let adView: FBAdView = FBAdView(placementID:"placement_id", adSize:kFBAdSize320x50, rootViewController:self)
                adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 50, width: width, height: height)
                self.view.addSubview(adView)

                adView.delegate = self
                FBAdSettings.addTestDevice("testdevice")
                adView.loadAd()

                println("worksssssssssfsdfsdfsdfsdf")
            }
        }

        func adView(adView: FBAdView!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
            adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
            adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: adBannerView.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height - adBannerView.frame.size.height / 2)
            adBannerView.delegate = self
            adBannerView.hidden = false
            view.addSubview(adBannerView)

            adView.hidden = true
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code showing how you're creating your FB ad and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fill rate in your developer settings refers to your **iAd fill rate only**. Set this to 100%. You should be creating your iAd `ADBannerView` and FB `FBAdView` globally and setting them up once your view loads in your `viewDidLoad`. Then, when your FB `FBAdView` fails to load you can just set your `ADBannerView`'s hidden property to `false`. The way you have it setup now you will be creating a new iAd `ADBannerView` each time your FB `FBAdView` fails to load an ad. Your code should end up looking very similar to this:

```
    // Create our FB and iAd banners globally
    var fbBannerAd: FBAdView = FBAdView()
    var iAdBannerAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // View loaded so lets setup our ads
    setupAds()
}

func setupAds() {
    // FB
    // Create FB banner ad with our placementID and select an adSize
    fbBannerAd = FBAdView(placementID:"placementID", adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner, rootViewController:self)
    // Set its frame relative to the screen
    fbBannerAd.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - fbBannerAd.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: fbBannerAd.frame.height)
    // Request ad from FB
    fbBannerAd.loadAd()
    // Set our ads delegate to 'self'
    fbBannerAd.delegate = self
    // Add our FB ad to our view
    self.view.addSubview(fbBannerAd)

    // iAd
    // Set its frame relative to the screen
    iAdBannerAd.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - iAdBannerAd.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: iAdBannerAd.frame.height)
    // Set our ads delegate to 'self'
    iAdBannerAd.delegate = self
    // Add our iAd ad to our view
    self.view.addSubview(iAdBannerAd)
    // Lets hide our iAd ad initially
    iAdBannerAd.hidden = true

    println("created our banner ads")
}

func adView(adView: FBAdView!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    // FB ad failed to load
    // Lets print the error so we know why
    println("failed to load fb ad with error: \(error)")

    // Also lets hide our FB ad because it doesn't have an ad to show
    fbBannerAd.hidden = true

    // And now we show our iAd ad
    iAdBannerAd.hidden = false
}

func adViewDidLoad(adView: FBAdView!) {
    // FB ad loaded an ad
    // Lets make sure it is shown and our iAd ad is hidden
    fbBannerAd.hidden = false
    iAdBannerAd.hidden = true
}
```

Then, to see what happens when your FB `FBAdView` fails you can call:

```
adView(fbBannerAd, didFailWithError: nil)
```

Comment: The reason I set the fill rate to 0% is that I wanted to test to see if my iAds would work when the FB ads has an error and don't show up. When I do this the FB ads still work for some reason and it doesnt get hidden.

Comment: I tried setting the iAds as the main banner ad and the FB ads as the fallback option and it worked. Why doesn't it work the other way around?

Comment: The code works but its still not showing the iAds when the FB Ads fail.

Comment: @coding22 how are you making your FB ad banner fail to receive an ad exactly?

Comment: Im going into settings-> developer in the iphone and setting the fill rate to 0%.

Comment: @coding22 that fill rate refers to **iAd's fill rate ONLY**

Comment: @coding22 I've edited my answer to include the function you can call to make the FB `FBAdView` fail. Add it to an action, a `UIButton` for example, and see what happens when it fires.